# How do I change the cursor in VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Somehow I ended up with a block/square cursor in VS Code. What is the setting name, and how do I go back to the pipe cursor?

Note that it's not "overtype" mode: I can type before other characters and it doesn't overwrite them.

I'm on macOS Sierra

Answer (score 39, accepted):

// Controls the cursor style, accepted values are 'block', 'line' and 'underline'

```
"editor.cursorStyle": "line",
```

from  [VSCode settings.json defaults](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace)

Answer (score 31):

I believe the reason is that you installed vim extension in vscode by mistake as it puts you in that mode by default until you press (i) to edit text. uninstall vim extension and things should go back to normal. or refer to [this](https://vim.rtorr.com/) vim cheatsheet for more information about using vim as a text editor.

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>Insert</kbd> it should return back to normal. You can also press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. In mac os it is control. Head back to code this problem can be cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I incorrectly wrote I was not in "insert" mode. I updated it to say I was not in "overtype" mode. This solution wouldn't work for this scenario, however, it is a common scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in my case it was caused due to the Vim extension in VS Code. If it is installed then try pressing "i" or uninstall the extension.

Comment: That's the same explanation as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64413713/2745495).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Vim extension installed:

The cursor styles can be set with the following lines in `settings.json`:

```
"vim.cursorStylePerMode.insert": "line",
"vim.cursorStylePerMode.normal": "block",
"vim.cursorStylePerMode.replace": "block",
"vim.cursorStylePerMode.visual": "block",
```

Answer (score 1):

open visual code editor ->Go To  Setting->Text Editor->Cursor
and change your cursor in Visual Code Studio

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I couldn't use the arrow keys to move the cursor past the end of line (to the next line) or before the beginning of line to the (previous line).
Uninstalling VIM and restarting VS Code fixed my problem

Comment: Sounds like we might be talking about two different things. I was able to change my cursor from "block" to "line" using the example from the selected answer.